# start/stop Unix partition

Tags: unix, partitioning

I would like to know the Unix Command for :

1. To see the Unix Box partitions.
2. how to start/stop Unix partition.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to mount a partition? http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_mount.htm

Comment: OR create and delete partitions? http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_fdisk.htm

Answer (score 4):

Making guesses at what you mean, I suggest:

1) To list all mounted drives:

```
mount
```

To find out how much space you have on each drive, and for a clearer display of which device corresponds to which directory, type:

```
df -h
```

2) To un-mount (remove) a drive:

```
umount /dev/hda
```

To mount (add/start) a drive:

```
mount /dev/hda
```

(where /dev/hda is the device you'd like to unmount)

To edit your partitions, try:

```
fstab
```

To find out more about these commands type:

```
man mount
```

or:

```
man df
```

or:

```
man fstab
```

respectively.

Comment: It should be added, that the fdisk-command can be used to show partition (and to change them).

Comment: I would add one more item to your post.  df -k will show the file system and which mounted partition it maps to.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking but here's some pointers about partitions in Unix.

- Type [`cat /etc/fstab`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?fstab+5) to see how the volumes are set up to be mounted at startup
- Use [`fdisk`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_fdisk.htm) to examine and edit hard disk partitions
- Use [`mount`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_mount.htm) to give you access to partitions/volumes from the root filesystem

Post a comment if you want more help on using any of those commands.

Comment: 'cat /etc/fstab' does not return the currently mounted volumes (that does the command mount without params), but defines the volumes the system should mount at startup.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited that line. It's been a little while since I've used fstab...

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that in UNIX your devices are shown as files in the `/dev/` folder, the best way to view all partitions is action `ls /dev/`.

For example, on FreeBSD:

```
$ ls -1 /dev/amrd*
/dev/amrd0
/dev/amrd0s1
/dev/amrd0s1a
/dev/amrd0s1b
/dev/amrd0s1c
/dev/amrd0s1d
/dev/amrd0s1e
```

On Linux the drives tend to be `sd*` or `hd*`, while OSX uses `disk*`.

Once you have your partition that you want to "start":

```
mount /dev/amrd0s1d /mnt/storage/
```

And to "stop" the partition:

```
umount /mnt/storage/
```

Check the `man pages` for either for more detailed uses.